# SQL Query with missing values that can be added from other entries

Tags: sql

I have a table in which some entries are not filled properly. Currently, there is no way for me to fix how the table is being filled, so for my Select statement I need to work around this. Here is what it looks like:

```
Name  | Address  | Value | Date
--------------------------------
Peter | New York | 10    | 03-26-18
Peter |          | 20    | 03-27-18
Peter | Chicago  | 15    | 03-28-18
```

In the sample I would need to fill the missing address with the value of address of the next date, e.g. Chicago. Final output should look like this:

```
Name  | Address  | Value | Date
--------------------------------
Peter | New York | 10    | 03-26-18
Peter | Chicago  | 20    | 03-27-18
Peter | Chicago  | 15    | 03-28-18
```

There is an edge case in which there might be two entries for the same name on the same date. In that case either entry is fine to be chosen as address. If this doesn't work, then that's ok too, a solution that doesn't cover the edge case would already help me as all my tries have resulted in duplicate entries.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL are you using, and are the dates always continuous?

Comment: Can you show us the query you're working with?
You can use something like SET Address = 'Chicago' where length(Address) = 0

Comment: I am using the latest version of Redshift, and no, the dates are not continuous. Just setting it to Chicago won't work either, this is just a sample and the addresses are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Address=B.Address
FROM TABLE_NAME A 
JOIN TABLE_NAME B
ON A.NAME=B.NAME AND A.DATE=DATEADD(DD, -1, B.DATE) 
WHERE A.Address IS NULL;
```

See a working [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/05f71/1).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is some sort of `ID` on the table you are selecting from, you can do this with `LEFT JOIN` the table on itself with the criteria to select the next record based on the `Date` column and only use the join result when the `Address` column is null or empty. This should handle your edge case and the non continuous dates. (Replace `test` with your table name)

```
select t1.name, 
case when t1.[address] is not null and len(t1.[address]) > 0 then t1.[address]
else t2.[address] end as [address], 
t1.value, t1.[date] from test t1
left join test t2 on t2.id = 
(select top 1 id from test where [date] >= t1.[date] and id <> t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I reworked the original query. I didn't take in to account for multiple missing values as your original table didn't have multiples missing, but I should thought of that in the first place. This should be what you're looking for. Hope it helps.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons](
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Address, Date)
VALUES
('Peter', 'New York', '2018-03-26'),
('Peter',  NULL, '2018-03-27'),
('Peter', 'Chicago', '2018-03-28'),
('Peter',  NULL, '2018-03-29'),
('Peter',  NULL, '2018-03-31'),
('Peter',  NULL, '2018-04-01'),
('Peter',  NULL, '2018-04-02'),
('Peter',  NULL, '2018-04-03'),
('Peter', 'Michigan', '2018-04-04')

GO
```

**Query:**

```
WITH CTE1(Name, Address, Date, DateRank) AS (
SELECT Name, Address, Date, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date ASC) AS DateRank FROM Persons
),

CTE2(Name, Address, Date, DateRank) AS (
SELECT Name, Address, Date, DateRank FROM CTE1 WHERE Address IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT 
    x.Name, 
    x.Address,
        CASE WHEN z.DateRank IS NULL 
            THEN COALESCE((SELECT TOP(1) ADDRESS FROM CTE2 WHERE x.DateRank < CTE2.daterank), 'NA')
            ELSE z.Address      
        END AS CombinedAddress,
    x.Date
FROM CTE1 x
LEFT JOIN CTE2 z ON x.DateRank = z.DateRank
ORDER BY x.Date ASC
```

**Results:**

```
Name | Address | CombinedAddress | Date
----------------------------------------
Peter   New York    New York    2018-03-26 
Peter   NULL        Chicago     2018-03-27 
Peter   Chicago     Chicago     2018-03-28 
Peter   NULL        Michigan    2018-03-29 
Peter   NULL        Michigan    2018-03-31 
Peter   NULL        Michigan    2018-04-01 
Peter   NULL        Michigan    2018-04-02 
Peter   NULL        Michigan    2018-04-03 
Peter   Michigan    Michigan    2018-04-04
```

### **Old Answer Below**

Personally I like a Rank function for this. Using CTE's in combination with Rank() gives you a lot of granular control for formatting later on. This is what I came up with. Hope it's helpful.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO Persons (Id, Name, Address, Date)
VALUES
(1, 'Peter', 'New York', '2018-03-26'),
(2, 'Peter', 'NULL', '2018-03-27'),
(3, 'Peter', 'Chicago', '2018-03-28'),
(4, 'Peter', 'NULL', '2018-03-29'),
(5, 'Peter', 'Michigan', '2018-03-31')

GO
```

Query:

```
WITH CTE1(Name, Address, Date, DateRank) AS (
SELECT Name, Address, Date, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date DESC) AS DateRank FROM Persons
), 

CTE2(Name, Address, Date, DateRank) AS (
SELECT Name, Address, Date, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date DESC) + 1 AS DateRank FROM Persons
),

Query(Name, Address, Date, CombinedAddress) AS (
    Select x.Name, 
    x.Address, 
    x.Date,
    Address = CASE
        WHEN x.DateRank % 2 = 0 THEN COALESCE(z.Address, 'NA')
        ELSE COALESCE(x.Address, 'NA')
        END
FROM CTE1 x
LEFT JOIN CTE2 z ON x.DateRank = z.DateRank
)

SELECT * FROM Query ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I think it is a good approach - it does not cover however the case when there are two dates in a row that have null values for the address.

Comment: @curzic I've updated the query so that it takes multiple missing values in to account. Hope that's close to what you're looking for!